# Python Tkinter how can I place background text in a textbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I am trying to place a greyed out background text inside a textbox, that disappears when someone begins to type. I have tried overlaying a label onto the textbox, but I could not get it to work. Here is some code I am running for the text box

```
root = tk.Tk()
S = tk.Scrollbar(root)
T = tk.Text(root, height=70, width=50)
S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", stop)
tk.mainloop()
```

How can I put in the background text?

Comment: You mean you want a Text in which for example "type here" is written and when someone click on that to write the above will be erased??

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a callback function you can remove the default text and change the foreground colour

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
e = tk.Entry(root, fg='grey')
e.insert(0, "some text")


def some_callback(event):  # must include event
    e.delete(0, "end")
    e['foreground'] = 'black'
    # e.unbind("<Button-1>")
    e.unbind("<FocusIn>")

    return None


# e.bind("<Button-1>", some_callback)
e.bind("<FocusIn>", some_callback)

e.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `<FocusIn>` instead is better.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about `placeholders` , tkinter does not have placeholder attribute for `Text` widget, but you do something similar with `Entry` widget . You have to do it manually, by binding an event with the Text widget.

```
text = tk.StringVar()
text.set('Placeholder text')
T = tk.Entry(root, height=70, width=50, textvariable = text)

def erasePlaceholder(event):

    if text.get() == 'Placeholder text':
        text.set('')

T.bind('<Button-1>', erasePlaceholder)
```

Try to ask if you face any issues.

Comment: I think I mistook the Entry widget feature with Text widget 

Comment: Edited the answer